# Is pattern.en wordnet limited?

Tags: python, nltk

Am trying to get synonyms of some words but find that some words give errors. This is the code.

```
from pattern.en import wordnet as wn

def foo():
    ss = 'man'    
    s = wn.synsets(ss)[0]
    name = [item for item in [str(x) for x in s.synonyms]] 
    print name
foo()
```

If I try with words such as pregnant or ugly, I get an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `pattern` wordnet interface work but you can use the `nltk` API instead, see http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: I find pattern to be very fast compared to nltk. you cantry it. Here is the link: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en

Comment: But i don't really want to debug the problem now ;P (at least not on the train, i'll take a look when i'm free if no one else finds out why it's not retrieving the synsets properly)

Comment: Could you try reinstalling pattern and see whether same problem happens? Are you only getting the IndexError from "man" or some other words? If it's some other words are they nouns/verbs/adjective/adverb? Or are they in princeton wordnet?

Comment: Had to reinstall pattern through this:> cd pattern-2.6
> python setup.py install. Still some words such as pregnant, ugly cant go through and I get the same error

Comment: one thing for example I note, is that if you use 'pregnancy', it works, but not 'pregnant'. Am working on a medical dictionary on this, that's why

Comment: In `pattern`, 'pregnant' and 'ugly' won't work without specifying the `pos` parameter ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there's some sort of discrepancy between NLTK wordnet and Pattern wordnet interface:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> from pattern.en import wordnet as pwn
>>> wn.synsets('man')
[Synset('man.n.01'), Synset('serviceman.n.01'), Synset('man.n.03'), Synset('homo.n.02'), Synset('man.n.05'), Synset('man.n.06'), Synset('valet.n.01'), Synset('man.n.08'), Synset('man.n.09'), Synset('man.n.10'), Synset('world.n.08'), Synset('man.v.01'), Synset('man.v.02')]
>>> pwn.synsets('man')
[Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'serviceman'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'homo'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'valet'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'Man'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'world')]
>>> len(wn.synsets('man'))
13
>>> len(pwn.synsets('man'))
11
```

Checking the official princeton wordnet, there are 13 synsets, see http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=man&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=

Checking the `pattern` code, it seems like there's something to do with the default POS being set to 'noun' (from [https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/en/wordnet/**init**.py#L93](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/en/wordnet/__init__.py#L93)).

But there's a "gotcha" where `pattern` library don't really work with strings when it comes to the POS parameter:

```
>>> pwn.synsets('man', pos='n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/text/en/wordnet/__init__.py", line 109, in synsets
    raise TypeError, "part of speech must be NOUN, VERB, ADJECTIVE or ADVERB, not %s" % repr(pos)
TypeError: part of speech must be NOUN, VERB, ADJECTIVE or ADVERB, not 'n'
>>> pwn.synsets('man', pos='NOUN')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pattern/text/en/wordnet/__init__.py", line 109, in synsets
    raise TypeError, "part of speech must be NOUN, VERB, ADJECTIVE or ADVERB, not %s" % repr(pos)
TypeError: part of speech must be NOUN, VERB, ADJECTIVE or ADVERB, not 'noun'
>>> pwn.synsets('man', pos='nn')
[Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'serviceman'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'homo'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'valet'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'Man'), Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'world')]
>>> pwn.synsets('man', pos='vb')
[Synset(u'man'), Synset(u'man')]
```

And now we found the 2 missing synsets.

**Q: Is pattern.en wordnet limited?**
**A:** No.

---

**Caveats of `pattern` API**

When using the WordNet API in `pattern`, you will need to specify the POS when it's not a noun, e.g.:

```
>>> from pattern.en import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('pregnant', pos='jj')
[Synset(u'pregnant'), Synset(u'meaning'), Synset(u'fraught')]
>>> wn.synsets('pregnant')
[]
>>> wn.synsets('quickly', pos='rb')
[Synset(u'quickly'), Synset(u'promptly'), Synset(u'cursorily')]
>>> wn.synsets('quickly')
[]
>>> wn.synsets('run', pos='nn')
[Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'test'), Synset(u'footrace'), Synset(u'streak'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'rivulet'), Synset(u'political campaign'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'discharge'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run')]
>>> wn.synsets('run', pos='vb')
[Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'scat'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'operate'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'function'), Synset(u'range'), Synset(u'campaign'), Synset(u'play'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'tend'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'prevail'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'carry'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'guide'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'run'), Synset(u'ply'), Synset(u'hunt'), Synset(u'race'), Synset(u'move'), Synset(u'melt'), Synset(u'ladder'), Synset(u'run')]
```

---

**Q: Then why am I getting that weird IndexError?**

**A:** Given the above checks, WordNet and Pattern are using the same exact Princeton WordNet 3.0 so there shouldn't be a problem. Possibly something had gone wrong when you downloaded/installed `pattern`, so try reinstalling it with:

```
pip install -U pattern
```

---

**Q: Is `pattern` faster than `nltk` for the wordnet access?**

**A:** Going to the speed issues, both `pattern` and `nltk` stores the synsets as dictionaries to be fetched, so I think retrieving from a dictionary is equivalent. There might be some overhead when loading `nltk` and the `wordnet` corpus, so it's best we timeit

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python -mtimeit 'from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.1 usec per loop
alvas@ubi:~$ python -mtimeit 'from pattern.en import wordnet as wn'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.702 usec per loop
alvas@ubi:~$ python -mtimeit 'from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn; wn.synsets("man")'
10 loops, best of 3: 22 usec per loop
alvas@ubi:~$ python -mtimeit 'from pattern.en import wordnet as wn; wn.synsets("man")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 81.8 usec per loop
```

Comment: from your comment , 'Checking the pattern code, it seems like there's something to do with the default POS being set to 'noun' ', I note that 'pregnant'==JJ and not NN in the POS for pattern, and that's the reason for the error